# Error restoring Postgresql db

Tags: database, postgresql, database-restore

I have a problem restoring a PostgreSQL DB which I have backup early using the following command:

```
pg_dump -i -h localhost -p 5432 -U Mark -F c -b -v -f "C:\Users\mchan\Desktop\MyDB\DBBackup.backup" mydb
```

Now When I try to restore this DB backup on (another machine) I got the following error:

```
pg_restore: [archiver] directory "C:\Users\mark\Desktop\MCHANBackups\DBBackup.backup" does not appear to be a valid archive ("toc.dat" does not exist)
```

Below is the command I used to restore the backup:

```
pg_restore -i -h localhost -p 5432 -U Mark -d mydb -v "C:\Users\mark\Desktop\MCHANBackups\DBBackup.backup"
```

Can someone please help me and tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Doing manually through command or pgadmin ?

Comment: I think you have used custom format and the backup is sent to normal text file. For restoring from text files, use psql command: psql -e -d template1 -f "C:\Users\mchan\Desktop\MyDB\DBBackup.backup"       Refer to this: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1069258949.26335.105.camel@linda.lfix.co.uk

Comment: @SatyamKoyani I am using command line

Comment: @r3ap3r I tried the psql command but it kept asking me about the Windows user (mchan) password, when I entered the password it gave me error (psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "mchan")...any idea why it is checking the windows password?

Comment: May be some firewall issue.Firewall security is turn on or off in your machine ?

Comment: @MChan Not sure why psql is asking for Windows User password. You can disable this authentication by replacing "md5" with **"trust"** in **pg_hba.conf** file under **"/data"** folder. For this modification to take effect , you will have to **restart** the "postgres service". Once this is done, you can retry the "psql" command. It **should** not ask for any password.

Comment: @r3ap3r Thanks, Now good news is that now it doesn't ask me for password, bad news is that it gave me a new error complaining that (role "mchan" does not exist)...how I can be specific towards which role to use in the psql command? Thanks in advance

Comment: @MChan use psql -U username -d databaseName . Refer to this link for more documentation on **"psql"** command :http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-psql.html . You will have to use a role that is defined in the database such as **postgres** or any other role that you might have created.

Comment: First, don't use `-i`, ever... Then, check the binaries version of each machine: `pg_dump -V` and `pg_restore -V`.

Comment: @r3ap3r Thanks a lot, it worked :) :) Can you please post your comments here as an answer so that I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have used custom format and the backup is sent to normal text file. For restoring from text files, use 
    psql command: psql -e -d template1 -f "C:\Users\mchan\Desktop\MyDB\DBBackup.backup" Refer to this [post](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1069258949.26335.105.camel@linda.lfix.co.uk) on Postgresql's Community page.

Use the **psql** command as follows:

```
psql -e -U username -d databaseName -f "C:\Users\mchan\Desktop\MyDB\DBBackup.backup"
```

Username should be a role defined in the database. Ex: **postgres**

If the **psql** command prompts for a password and you don't know the password for the user, replace "md5" with **"trust"** in **pg_hba.conf** file under "/data" folder and *restart* "postgres service" for this change to take effect.

Once this change is done **psql** will not prompt for the password.

For more documentation on *psql* and additional options , refer to [psql-doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-psql.html).